# How encode categorical data without affecting numerical data in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
     Loan_ID    Gender  Married Dependents  Education   ApplicantIncome
1   LP001003    Male     Yes        1       Graduate       4583
2   LP001005    Male     Yes        0       Graduate       3000
3   LP001006    Male     Yes        0       Not Graduate   2583
4   LP001008    Male     No         0       Graduate       6000
5   LP001011    Male     Yes        2       Graduate       5417
```

> How to encode 'Gender', 'Married', 'Education' columns without affecting
>   'Loan_ID', 'Dependents','ApplicantIncome' columns.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research?

Comment: I tried " df.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform) " this works but when I cancat this df frame with another data frame then I'm getting Nan values.

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = LabelEncoder()

for cat_var in ['Gender', 'Married', 'Education']:
    df[cat_var] = le.fit_transform(df[cat_var])
```

Comment: Better initialize LabelEncoder per class, otherwise you won't be able to perform inverse transformation (that is often needed later when improving or troubleshooting the model).

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) method, so:

```
ohe_df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Gender', 'Married', 'Education'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Label Encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html):

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le1 = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['Gender'] =le1.fit_transform(df['Gender'])
le2 = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['Married'] =le2.fit_transform(df['Married'])
le3 = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['Education'] =le3.fit_transform(df['Education'])
```

This approach will use a different label encoder for every column, that will also mean that you will have the same number in different columns.

When you run one label encoder for all, the number will be only the same if it exactly the same word.

After your classification, you can inverse the labels with:

```
df['Married'] = le2.inverse_transform(df['Married']
```

Comment: What if there are 80 columns in a dataset and need to encode, this will take a lot of time, so are there any other ways to encode all the dataset without affecting numerical columns.

Comment: the solution for natheer will do it, but you cannot do inverse transformation then

Comment: What is the use of inverse transformation? and how to perform it.

Comment: Inverse transformation is not relevant for the classification itself, it is only interessting if you want to check after your classification what is the original value...the code is written in my answer already

Comment: Thank you PV8, by the way how to learn all these in detail. I mean machine learning, because I couldn't find the correct resource.

Comment: Visit an online course somewhere, you should google: coursera + machine learning for example...

Comment: Thank You so much. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

While preparing your data consider few things:

1. LoanID column is ordinal Categorical data and it needs to be converted to numerical using one hot encoding as algorithms only understand numerics
2. Label encoder works well for binary class for multi class try using one hot encoder or factorize
3. Create separate columns for numerical and converted categorical data and concat in one df for training and test split

As an example to your question:

```
#create ndarray for label encodoing (sklearn)
Gender = data.iloc[:,1:2].values
Married = data.iloc[:,2:3].values
Education = data.iloc[:,4:3].values

## le for Gender
le = LabelEncoder()
Gender[:,0] = le.fit_transform(Gender[:,0])
Gender = pd.DataFrame(Gender)
Gender.columns = ['Gender']
le_Gender_mapping = dict(zip(le.classes_, le.transform(le.classes_)))
print("Sklearn label encoder results for Gender:")  
print(le_Gender_mapping)

**Do the same for 'Married' and 'Education' as they are also binary

Load_ID = data.iloc[:,0:1].values #ndarray

## ohe for Loan_ID
ohe = OneHotEncoder() 

Load_ID = ohe.fit_transform(Loan_ID).toarray()
Load_ID = pd.DataFrame(Load_ID)
print("Sklearn one hot encoder results for Load_ID:") 

##put data together

X_num = data[['Applicant_Income']].copy()
X_final = pd.concat([Loan_ID, Gender, Married, Education, X_num], axis = 1)

This prepares your initial data set, take out column you want to predict as y_final and do the train test split.

Note: After train test split do Normalize or Standardize(preferred as less affected by outliers) otherwise the Applicant_income will dominate the predictions
```

Comment: You have given clear information but I want to learn deep coding where can I learn?

Comment: Keep the fundamentals clear, get the clarity of the requirement and what kind of model you want to make, study the data carefully, jot down the necessary preprocessing steps and feature scaling steps. Keep practicing